# iOS 7 UINavigationBar Retina image size

Tags: ios, image, ios7, uinavigationbar, retina

Here I have an image, backgroundTest1@2x.png, that is 640 x 128, with the red portion being 320 x 64.

[image]

But when I set the image like so:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundTest1@2x.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I get only red in the navigation bar:
[image]

What's going on here and what size and name should I be using in my iOS 7 / retina only app? If the '@2x' should be included, then how come 320 x 64 is the image size that 'works'?

Comment: You don't need the `@2x.png`, what does it look like if you take that off?

Comment: It now works as expected, thank you. I suppose I shouldn't have literally taken the phrase, 'You only need @2x files in your app bundle' that I read in http://bendodson.com/weblog/2013/10/16/dropping-non-retina-support-in-ios7/

Comment: I'll claim that as an answer ha! Added some more info for you too - the docs explain it all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `@2x.png` as the system takes care of picking the correct images for you based on the `-[UIScreen scale]` (`png` hasn't been need since iOS 4 either).
See the [docs (`+[UIImage imageNamed:]`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10) for more info!